# Copying csv data obtained using .read() to postgresql database using Python 3.5

Tags: python, postgresql, csv, flask

I want to copy a csv data without uploading the actual csv to my folder. Currently, I can get the csv data via the following code:

```
f = request.files['data_file'].read()
    a = f.decode('utf-8')
```

If I would print `a`, I can get the data from the csv. My problem is that how do I copy this data to my postgresql database? I tried using the `copy` command in postgresql but it needs a path to the file and I don't want to store the actual csv I just want it to be copied directly in my postgres database. Im using python 3.

Comment: psycopg2.copy_to

Answer (score 0):

Using one of the `psycopg2.copy_*` methods is the way to go. Which one will depend on -

- Does the csv have a header?
- Does the csv structure match the table *exactly* (number and type of columns)?

Note #1 - The form of the copy command that takes a path expects that path to exist on *the database server*. In Heroku, that will never be the case. Instead, you need the form of the command like this: `copy table_name from stdin...`. The `copy_from` method is a convenience method for that form.

1) Simplest case - comma-delimited file with no headers exactly matching the table structure:

```
stmt.copy_from(request.files['data_file'], 'your_table', sep=',')
```

(`stmt` is a cursor, preferably used inside a `with conn.cursor() as stmt:` clause)

2) No header, but csv only has a subset of the columns:

```
stmt.copy_from(request.files['data_file'], 'some_table', sep=',', cols=['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])
```

3) If you have a header, you will need `copy_expert` -

```
sql = """
    copy some_table (col1, col2, col3)
    from stdin with csv header delimiter ','
"""
stmt.copy_expert(sql, request.files['data_file'])
```

Note #2 - the data will be implicitly converted to the correct type. It will also need to satisfy data constraints. A failure of either operation for a single record kills the entire transaction. As a result, you may need to get fancy and load all the data into a simple temp table, clean it, then do a `select into` (

Note #3 - I kinda guessed that you can use `request.files` directly, but did not test it. If that fails, stream the data to a temp file and use that as the argument to the copy method.

See:

- http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.copy_from